# gnome clock direction is reversed

Tags: gnome

Telling Ubuntu I'm from Israel sets all sort of locale into Hebrew (as I've asked before). One of these settings is applied for the Gnome Shell (which I use as a DE) and sets the calender to Hebrew. I'm OK with that, but, since Hebrew is RTL language, the RTL tag is applied to the clock which now tells me the time is 48:20, instead of 20:48 (for example). Can I fix this? I know that this might be a bug that I should report, but it might related that I tend to test DE and WM quite often and it might be some clashing setting I should rule out first.

Comment: Please see this for more information: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602830/gnome-shell-inverted-clock/606477#606477